# Click into a button within Wpf application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, grid, dockpanel

I have this snippet :

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:external="clr-namespace:ToggleSwitch;assembly=ToggleSwitch"
        xmlns:modern="clr-namespace:Tools.Views.New_Project"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Assergs.Windows.Controls;assembly=Assergs.Windows"
        x:Class="Tools.FirstInterface"
        Title="Nouveau projet" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"
    WindowStyle="None"
        >

    <Grid  >
        <DockPanel>
        <Grid   DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="38" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="LightGray"  >
        <Button Content="Annuler"   Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="80" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,8" BorderBrush="CadetBlue"  BorderThickness="2" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Times New Roman"  />
        <Button Content="Suivant >>"  Background="#FFF9F7F7" Margin="0,0,94,8" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="81" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0" BorderBrush="CadetBlue"  BorderThickness="2" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" Click="Button_Click_4"/>
        <Button Content="&lt;&lt; Précédent" Background="White" Margin="0,0,180,8" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="82" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" BorderBrush="CadetBlue"  BorderThickness="2" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold"/>

      </Grid>
            <UserControl x:Name="container"></UserControl>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The problem is that the buttons in the grid are not clickable !!! even i add this method in the code behind :

```
private void Button_Click_4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hello world!!");
        }
```

When i click into the button nothing happens.

**Edit**
I think the problem comes from the user control

```
<UserControl x:Class="Tools.Views.New_Project.TypeOfProject"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 

             >
    <Grid  >
        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="2132" Margin="0,0,-1163,-684" Height="828" VerticalAlignment="Top"  >
            <Expander Header="Positionnement"  VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Left" BorderThickness="4" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Times New Roman">
                <DockPanel>
                    <Label Height="28"  Margin="10,10,10,0" Cursor="Hand" Content="Positionnement 2D" DockPanel.Dock="Top" MouseDoubleClick="Label_MouseDoubleClick_1" MouseUp="Label_MouseDoubleClick_1" FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Times New Roman"/>
                    <Label Height="28"  Margin="10,10,10,0" Cursor="Hand" Content="Positionnement 3D" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" MouseDoubleClick="Label_MouseDoubleClick_2" MouseUp="Label_MouseDoubleClick_2" FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Times New Roman"/>

                </DockPanel>
            </Expander>
            </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="2132" Margin="0,113,-1163,-729" Height="760" VerticalAlignment="Top"  >
            <Expander Header="Métrologie"  VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Left"  BorderThickness="4" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic">
                <DockPanel>
                    <Label Height="28"  Margin="10,10,10,0" Cursor="Hand" Content="Métrologie1D" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" MouseDoubleClick="Label_MouseDoubleClick_3" MouseUp="Label_MouseDoubleClick_3"  FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Times New Roman"/>
                    <Label Height="28"  Margin="10,10,10,0" Cursor="Hand" Content="Métrologie2D" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" MouseDoubleClick="Label_MouseDoubleClick_3" MouseUp="Label_MouseDoubleClick_3"  FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Times New Roman"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </Expander>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="2138" Margin="-119,220,-1050,-875" Height="799" VerticalAlignment="Top"  >

            <Expander Header="Classification"   BorderThickness="4" Margin="0,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="2016" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Height="234" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsExpanded="True">

            </Expander>
     </DockPanel>
        <GroupBox Header="" Height="182" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="219,38,0,-76" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="402"/>
        <Label   Margin="248,79,-66,31" Cursor="Hand" Content="Algorithme1" DockPanel.Dock="Right" x:Name="algo1"/>
        <Label   Margin="248,161,-61,-47"  Cursor="Hand" Width="Auto"  Content="Algorithme2" DockPanel.Dock="Right" x:Name="algo2" />
        <Label   Margin="248,118,-66,-12" Cursor="Hand" Width="Auto"  Content="Algorithme3" DockPanel.Dock="Right"  x:Name="algo3"/>
        <GroupBox Header="Présentation de type du programme" Height="182" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="621,38,0,-76"  FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Times New Roman"/>
         <Label  Content="dddddd" Margin="626,76,0,-76"/>
        <GroupBox Header="" Margin="219,220,0,-280" Height="204" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Label Content="Nom: " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="87" Margin="0,39,0,0"/>

        </GroupBox>
        <Label Content="Emplacement: " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99" Margin="224,330,0,-221"/>
        <TextBox Margin="321,276,243,-155" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Margin="323,330,241,-209" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Name="browser"  Content="Parcourir...."  Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="774,330,108,-209"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

1. Why?
2. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works fine. Please re-check your code for any mistakes. I tested your code and it worked fine. There may be some other issue.Ia there any other codes you have written.??

Comment: thanks , i think the same because i change to another user control and it works , please see my edit